# Spring Roo and was.policy file

Tags: java, security, websphere, spring-roo

I am deploying a **Spring Roo** application on Websphere and I need to implement **Java 2 Security** in that application. When I enable the Java 2 security on the server and deploy the application, it gives me **this error**:

```
Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: MyApplication
Error Stack:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere 7.0\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\antonNode01Cell\MyApplication-1_0_30_BUILD-SNAPSHOT_war.ear\MyApplication-1.0.30.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\WEB-INF\classes\com\transoftinc\vlm\myapp\annotations\CSV.class]; nested exception is java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:237)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:204)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84) 
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1335)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1708)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:381)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
 ...
```

I believe the problem is security settings for the application. (Or the absence of them.) Normally, Websphere expects a **was.policy** file to be included in the EAR, which defines these settings. However, because I am deploying a WAR - there is no apparent way to supply that file. If I drop it into either of the two META-INF directories in my application - the error is the same. As if, Websphere was not finding the was.policy file.

My was.policy file:

```
grant codeBase "file:${application}" {
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:${jars}" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:${connectorComponent}" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:${webComponent}" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:${ejbComponent}" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Question:

**How can I define security settings for my application?**

And really, my goal is just to give all permissions and move on. I hope this is possible somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe META-INF/was.policy is only supported for EARs, not standalone WARs.  Suggestions:

1. Create an EAR around the WAR and create the file there.
2. Deploy the WAR as a standalone module, but update the application to add the file after deploying it.  While deploying, the product will create an EAR around the WAR.  It should be possible to use AdminApp.update with partialapp to do add the single file.
3. Disable Java 2 security.  If you're granting AllPermission to your application anyway, what's the point?
4. Add the permissions to PROFILE_HOME/config/cells/CELL/nodes/NODE/app.policy.  This would affect all applications, though.
5. Add the permissions to PROFILE_HOME/properties/server.policy.  This requires hard-coding the path (or setting a system property in the server JVM and using that).

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is what I thought - you cannot add was.policy to WARs. The reason why I have this problem is that we do need to implement Java 2 security for this application, but while in development I can grant AllPermission. Our clients may use other settings. I want to try your solution #2... But can't I just add was.policy into the generated EAR directory and restart the app for the same effect?

Comment: Yes, depending on how much you want to rely on internals.  I believe you'll need to add the file in PROFILE_HOME/config/cells/CELL/applications/APP.ear/deployments/APP/META-INF/, not PROFILE_HOME/installedApps/CELL/APP.ear/META-INF/.  AdminApp.update with partialapp abstracts the paths at the cost of increased complexity.